# Bison prints my custom cout backward

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to reproduce how cout is working using flex and bison. For example:

```
cout << "hello world";
```

will print:

```
hello world
```

It's working great when there's only one parameter, but I have trouble once I'm putting multiple variables.

```
cout << "I like " << "bananas" << endl;
```

will print

```
\nbananasI like
```

instead of

```
I like bananas\n
```

I guess that it's because it parses the whole line before printing so it begins by "endl" then "bananas" and then "I like" but I don't get how to reverse it. I tried to rearrange my token in multiple setups to reverse the priority like for multiplication and addition but with no success so far.

These are the useful parts of myfile.y

```
%union {
    char* string;
}

%token <string> STRING
%token ENDL
%token COUT
%token INSERT

%%

displayBegin :
   COUT displayContent
;

displayContent :
  ';'
| INSERT displayEnd
| INSERT STRING displayContent { printf("%s",$2); }
;

displayEnd :
  ENDL ';' { printf("\n"); }
;

%%
```

Same for myfile.l

```
"cout"                  { return COUT; }
"endl"                  { return ENDL; }
"<<"                    { return INSERT; }
[\"][^\"]+[\"]          { char* tmp = strdup(yytext); tmp++; tmp[strlen(tmp)-1] = '\0'; yylval.string = tmp; return STRING; }
```

---

I edited myfile.y as follow and it works but as it's double recursive it's not that great (shows a warning at compilation time):

```
displayBegin :
  COUT INSERT displayContent
;

displayContent :
  ';'
| displayEnd
| STRING { printf("%s",$1); }
| displayContent INSERT displayContent
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the `<<` operator is *left-associative*, which means that `a << b << c` is the same as `((a << b) << c)`. If it were right-associative (like the assignment operator), the grouping would be nested in the other direction: `(a << (b << c))`.

Although that looks like it is purely semantic, it also reflects the way the strings are parsed. In particular, the *innermost* expression must be reduced first, because the result of the reduction is one of the arguments to the next innermost non-terminals in the next innermost expression. And if the evaluation is being performed by the reduction actions, the evaluation order will be determined by the reduction order.

In short, if you want to do immediate evaluation and you want the evaluation of `<<` to be left-to-right, you need to make sure that `<<` is parsed as left-associative.

In general terms, left-associative operators are associated with left-recursive productions, while right-associative operators are associated with right-recursive productions. Your original definition was right-recursive, so that the production

```
displayContent: INSERT STRING displayContent
```

requires that the `displayContent` on the right be reduced (and consequently printed) before the `STRING` can be included in an outer `displayContent`. In other words, it evaluates right-to-left, which is undesirable. (It also fails to really represent the semantics of the expression, since the `<<` operator is not associated with its left-hand operand.)

Your second definition is ambiguous, although that could be fixed with a precedence declaration. But it is useful to write the grammar out in a non-ambiguous form, if only to show what the precedence declaration does. So here's the left-associative (and left-recursive) grammar:

```
displayStatement: display ';' ;

display: COUT
       | display "<<" STRING  { printf("%s",$3); } 
       | display "<<" ENDL    { putchar('\n');   }
       ;
```

Unlike the original grammar, this one allows multiple instances of `endl` and does not require that the line end with one. So it's much closer to C++. But it still doesn't quite reflect C++ semantics, because it fails to show how the left-hand operator of `<<` is used. In particular, the left-hand operator and the result are streams; in C terms, that could be a `FILE*`. So let's do it that way:

```
%union {
    char* string;
    FILE* file;
}

%token <string> STRING
%token ENDL   "endl"
%token COUT   "cout"
%token INSERT "<<"
%type <file> display

%%

displayStatement: display ';' ;

display: "cout"               { $$ = stdin;                     }
       | display "<<" STRING  { fprintf($1, "%s", $3); $$ = $1; } 
       | display "<<" "endl"  { putc('\n', $1);        $$ = $1; }
       ;
```

That will make it much easier to add the ability to output to stderr; all that is necessary is to add `cerr` to the lexer, and  add a production to `display`: "cerr" { $$ = stderr; }`.

As a final note, you correctly call `strdup` in your scanner so that you can pass a copy of `yytext` to the parser. But you never `free()` the duplicated string so you end up leaking memory. As a first step, you might want to free the string after it is printed, making the second `display` production's action:

```
{ fprintf($1, "%s", $3); free($3); $$ = $1; }
```

Also take a look at bison's `%destructor` declaration to see how to avoid leaking memory in the case of a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The input is parsed recursively. A rule will be parsed successfully after everything in it is parsed. So, in your case, the first thing to be parsed successfully will be the `displayEnd`, printing the `\n`, then that gets rolled up to the immediate upper level, which then gets printed, etc.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see. However I don't really see how to parse it differently. I made it "double recursive" (`displayContent INSERT displayContent`) the way I do my operations and it displays correctly but it shows a warning (shift/reduce) because of it. It's better in my opinion as it works but I'd like to make it work with no warning.

Comment: There is no need to parse it differently. For example, you could print the whole thing once you have finished parsing everything (at the `displayBegin` rule)